# Do i need a separate database when making a game in Unity3D With Android Games services, Apple Game Center and Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, game-center

I am creating a Mobile game in unity3D with Android Games services, Apple Game Center, and Facebook and I was wondering if I need a  separate database to store different variables like boosters, currency, etc, or can I use these services to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it depends of game you're making.

But overall answer is "YES"

You may want to save some sensitive data like currency/boosters/daily rewards and do a server-side validation.

**You can't trust the player.**

Without a server-side validation and a DB it would be difficult to validate if player really waited for the next daily reward or he just switched the date/time on his phone.

Same with currency/boosters: without a server side validation and a DB you'll have to save data in playerPrefs. Player can find playerPrefs location and change the amount of currency and you'll never be able to check it.